# Storing / passing a variable to another function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem storing and passing a variable from one function to another. My script should work like this:

```
<input type="text" id="ip1" >    
         <input type="button" id="check_button" value="checking" onclick="check_text()">
         <input type="button" id="write_button" value="write" onclick="write()">
<p id="ag"></p>
```

If somebody enters a value in the input field `"ip1"` and presses the `"check_button"`, the value should be stored in a variable. This variable should be written in the innerHTML of `"ag"` when the `"write_button"` is clicked.

This is my JS. I am aware that this cannot work, I just don't know how to do it properly. I found similar problems but the solution always seems to complex for a beginner like myself to understand. A very easy solution would be very much appreciated!

```
            function check_text() {
                var ui = document.getElementById('ip1').value;
            }

            function write() {
                document.getElementById('ag').innerHTML = ui;
            }
```

Comment: Why not use just one button that when clicked you get the value and pass it to the paragraph in one go?

Comment: I just wanted to know the solution to this exact problem since I want to understand the logic behind it. You're 100% correct, using 1 button would solve the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare variable outside the function:
it must work

```js
var ui = 0;
function check_text() {
 ui = document.getElementById('ip1').value;
}

function writeL() {
  document.getElementById('ag').innerHTML = ui;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="ip1" >    
             <input type="button" id="check_button" value="checking" onclick="check_text()">
             <input type="button" id="write_button" value="write" onclick="writeL()">
    <p id="ag"></p>
```

Comment: If I declare `var ui = 0;`, the result (what will be written in 'ag') is 0 and not the value that is entered in the input field.
Also I noticed that I cannot name my function write(). Seems like write() is not allowed as a function name.

Comment: can you please mark my answer as right answer, just put V near the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are of course more than one way to process your value. The Snippet below uses the [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/). Details are commented in the Snippet. BTW, I had to get rid of one of the buttons, it would probably hinder your understanding rather than aid it. It's better to visualize what's happening by watching the console.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/***NOTE: Any comment having a pencil icon: ✎
|| means that the expression/statement is there...
||...to show an alternate way. Although they...
||...aren't used in the functions, they can be...
||...used instead of it's counterpart.
*/


function processData() {

  // Reference the <form> by id or...

  var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
  // ✎
  /*1*/
  console.log('1. This is ' + form1.id + '\n');

  /*...or by HTMLFormControlsCollection...
  ||...reference <form> as the first <form>...
  ||...the .forms is an array-like object...
  ||...the [0] is the index indicating which...
  ||...<form> it's referring to. This is easily...
  ||...determined since there's only one <form>...
  ||...on the page.
  */

  var formA = document.forms[0];
  /*2*/
  console.log('2. This is ' + formA.id + '\n');

  // We'll continue using the HTMLFormControlsCollection

  /* This is using previously declared formA to...
  ||...reference it's .elements property. The...
  ||...elements property is like the .forms...
  ||...except that it refers to a <form>'s...
  ||...field form elements like <input> and ...
  ||...<output>
  */

  var formUI = formA.elements;
  /*3*/
  console.log('3. This is an ' + formUI + '\n');

  // We can get the number of form control elements

  var qty = formUI.length;
  // ✎
  /*4*/
  console.log('4. form1 has ' + qty + ' form control  elements\n');

  /* Get the value of text1 by using the object formUI...
  ||...the name of <input>, and the .value property.
  */

  var TXT1 = formUI.text1.value;
  /*5*/
  console.log('5. The value of text1 is ' + TXT1 + '\n');

  /* We can get the same result by referencing <input>...
  || ...by it's index position in the formUI object...
  || This expression is getting the value of the first...
  ||...form field element of the <form> or formUI object
  */
  var TXTA = formUI[0].value;
  // ✎
  /*6*/
  console.log('6. The value of Text1 is still ' + TXTA + '\n');


  /* Return the value of TXT1
  || This function returns a value, so it can be...
  ||...assigned to a var as a value and it can be...
  ||...passed through another function like a...
  ||...parameter.
  */
  return TXT1;
}

/* This will pass a value...
||...reference the <output>...
||...and set <output> value to...
||...given value
*/
function displayData(value) {
  var output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
  output1.value = value;
}

/* When button1 is clicked...
||...store the return of processData() in a var...
||...then pass that var to displayData() function
*/
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(event) {
  var VAL = processData();
  displayData(VAL);
}
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<form id='form1' name='form1'>
  <input type="text" id="text1" name='text1'>
  <input type="button" value="display" id='button1'>
  <br/>
  <output id="output1" name='output1'></output>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with jQuery like this:

```js
            var enteredValue = "";
            $("#check_button").on("click", function() {
              enteredValue = $("#ip1").val();
            });
            $("#write_button").on("click", function() {
              $('#store_value').html(enteredValue);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ip1" />    
         <input type="button" id="check_button" value="checking" />
         <input type="button" id="write_button" value="write" />
<p id="store_value"></p>
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for jQuery. Take that into account. Check [**this**](http://needsmorejquery.com/)!

Comment: just an additional answer

Comment: This looks like a simple task that can be done using just JS. And OP doesn't seem to be using jQuery, so why force him to use jQuery.

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, I am not trying to solve this exact problem, but rather understand the logic behind it, so I can apply it to other cases. (with Javascript)
I appreciate the jQuery solution, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much